# Table view did select method to handle check box image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an table view with three cell which contains the label and one image (check box).Now when ever i select any cell.That particular cell image (check box) alone needs to get `tick.png`. And remaining two cell image should be `untick.png`.

But now if i select first cell then the first cel image get as tick.png.Then if i select second and third cell.That cell image also getting `tick.png`

But i need only one image alone needs to `tick.png`.Which ever table view cell i am selecting that particular cell image alone needs to be `tick.png`.And remaining two cell image should be `untick.png`.

My code :

```
var Data: [String] = ["First","Second","Third"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.Data.count > 0{
        return self.Data.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewCell

    cell.Lbl.text = self.aData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! suggestionCell
    cell.suggestionImg.image = UIImage(named: "tick")


}
```

Comment: do you want multiple selection or single selection ?

Comment: @ junaidUmer  single seletion only

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614938-allowsmultipleselection This is what you are looking for, In your viewDidload set it to false. that should do.

Comment: if you could use button that will be easy but in your case you can do it multiple ways whats comming in my mind now is to give tags.. in your cell for row at index path give tag 0 to each image view and when image view selected change tag to if .. in did select row u can chk if tag is one change image to unselected one and if tag 0 change image  to unchecked and update tag respectively...

Comment: you can also chk image identifier.... and a boolen can also do that

Comment: A little question... why did you create an populate your table with `ViewCell` in `cellForRowAt` but manipulate it as `suggestionCell` in `didSelectRowAt`? are these two classes sub/super class of each other?

Comment: Sorry its` suggestionCell`. but then also i am getting same as i explained here `i update ur answer. But now first cell is already as selected state.And if i press second cell.The first and secons cell has tick mark. If i press third cell then second and third cell having think mark`

Comment: give me a moment, I am double checking my logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you only want a single check mark at any given time. If this is true then you would simply setup a property in your view controller like this:

```
var checkedRow: Int
```

and set the row index in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`. By setting it to `-1` you would disable all check marks. Then in `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:`) you would conditionally enable the check mark for the cell if `indexPath.row` is equal to `checkedRow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    checkedRow = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewCell
    if indexPath.row == checkedRow {
        cell.suggestionImg.image = UIImage(named: "tick.png")
        cell. suggestionLbl.text = "<ticked text>"
    } else {
        cell.suggestionImg.image = UIImage(named "untick.png")
        cell. suggestionLbl.text = "<unticked text>"
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am new to this. But i am not sure how to handle in `didSelectRowAt` and in `cellForRowAt`. If u give in code wise solution.I can learn from that.

Comment: I understand about the did select part.I already did code like `checkedRow = indexPath.row`.But i dont know how to handle in cellForRowAt

Comment: I've enhanced my code sample. Please give it a try.

Comment: but by default first cell image has tick mark.If i try to select any cell.The tick image is not chnaging

Comment: Would you like to show me your `ViewCell` class? Maybe the issue lies there.

Comment: @TomE I think you forgot to reload after `didSelectRowAt` so the new data is not reflected visually.

Comment: @TomE   `IBOutlet weak var suggestionLbl: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var suggestionImg: UIImageView!`

Comment: @Ben Ong: Thanks, just added the missing line.

Comment: @TomE Now its worked. But tell me one thing. i set `var checkedRow: Int = 0` so my first cell is as tick image. how can i get the cell label text.where my tick image was there in any cell

Comment: @david: Good to hear you got it going. I added some more code to the `cellForRow` part. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

As an add-on to Tom's answer, I suggest storing IndexPath instead of Int adding also a

```
var lastCheckedRow:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
```

This allows you to only reload the newly checked row and the previously checked row instead of the whole table view plus it will support multiple sections too. It does not matter much at your current stage where there is only 3 rows but for larger table views this will be more efficient. Also it removes the blinking effect of UITableView.reloadData().
The code is something like:

```
//0 based on assumption that first cell is checked by default
var checkedRow:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
var lastCheckedRow:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Update checkedRow for reload but keep track of current tick
    lastCheckedRow = checkedRow
    checkedRow = indexPath

    //Remove previous tick
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [lastCheckedRow], with: .automatic)

    //Update new tick
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [checkedRow], with: .automatic)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewCell
    if indexPath.row == checkedRow {
        cell.suggestionImg.image = UIImage(named: "tick.png")
    } else {
        cell.suggestionImg.image = UIImage(named "untick.png")
    }
    return cell
}
```

You can also play around to create an ideal visual effect when ticking different cell by changing the `with:UITableViewRowAnimation` parameter which I use `.automatic` for the example.

Comment: Same i am getting.Initially first cell is selected.And if i select second and third cell there also image is changing to tick as multiple.At last all cell are as tick iamge

Comment: `let currentCheckedRow = checkedRow`.Here `checkedRow` is wr needs to declare.Are it is `lastCheckedRow`

Comment: `currentCheckedRow` is just a temporally storage of `checkedRow` so that we can reload the currently checked row to remove the tick before we update `lastCheckedRow`, I also update the fact that you need to declare `checkedRow` before these

Comment: i update ur answer. But now first cell is already as selected state.And if i press second cell.The first and secons cell has tick mark. If i press third cell then second and third cell having think mark

Comment: My bad... I made a little mistake resulting in the bug. I have corrected it and updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Also noticed I think too much, not need for a temp variable actually... and if you make the `checkedRow` and `lastCheckedRow` store IndexPath instead this become capable of supporting multiple sections

Answer (score 0):

[allowsMultipleSelection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614938-allowsmultipleselection): Is only easiest thing that will help you. 
Add following line in your `viewDidLoad` after setting up the `tableView`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // ... setup you need

    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false

}
```

Hope this helps!